# How to use Etag in Youtube Data API V3

Tags: java, youtube, etag, youtube-data-api

I have written a java program using YouTube data API v3 to get the list of video-Ids based on some keyword.
I want to use etag to verify whether there is some new video-Ids in the returned list when I run the program again but I am not able to find any proper documentation how to use etag logic.

Can anybody please guide how to use it or if anybody has implemented this.

Thanks!